# Url.Link not working in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, url-helper

Using the unit test below .. Iam trying to test my webapi.

```
[Test]
public void CheckControllerForCreate()
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/product");
    var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Foo", "api/{controller}/{id}");
    var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "products" } });
    var controller = new ProductController
    {
        ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request),
        Request = request,
        Url = new UrlHelper(request)
    };

    controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;

    var result = controller.Create(new Product {Id = 4, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1});
}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Create(Product product)
{
    var url = Url;
    if (product == null)
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage{StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,ReasonPhrase = "Product is not specified"});
    products.Add(product);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, product);
    string uri = Url.Link("Foo", product.Id);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
    return response;
}
```

The Create Action throws an exception because `uri` is `null`. Now, the Url helper is correctly picking up the RouteName , otherwise there would be a RouteName not found exception. I am assuming that somethign is wrong with my configuration.

I referred to http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/16/unit-testing-asp-dot-net-web-api and several other posts for unit testing the controllers.

The WebAPI method is here on codeplex

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1acb241299a8#src/System.Web.Http/Routing/UrlHelper.cs

Edit

I have narrowed it down to vpd being null in ( UrlHelper)

```
IHttpVirtualPathData vpd = configuration.Routes.GetVirtualPath(
                request: request,
                name: routeName,
                values: routeValues);
```

Can't seem to figure out why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the routeData into the request, the same way you did with the configuration:

```
controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;
```

Also you are incorrectly using the `Url.Link` helper. You haven't specified a controller nor you have indicated the id.

The code in your controller should look like this:

```
string uri = Url.Link("Foo", new { id = product.Id, controller = "product" });
```

---

UPDATE:

Here's a full example.

Controller:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Create(int id)
    {
        var uri = Url.Link("Foo", new { id = id, controller = "product" });
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, uri);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
// arrange
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/product");
var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Foo", "api/{controller}/{id}");
var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "product" }));
var controller = new ProductController
{
    ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request),
    Request = request,
    Url = new UrlHelper(request)
};
controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;

// act
var result = controller.Create(4);

// assert
...
```

Comment: Alright, lemme write an entire working test for you then. See my updated answer for a full working example.

Comment: I think my route config is wrong.. my intent is to be able to pass a product to my controller ...right now you are passing an integer and the route also is for the same..do I need to fix something in my routing ?

Comment: No, you don't need to be fixing anything. Just replace the integer with a product and it's gonna work.

Comment: Yup.. I was attaching the routeData in the wrong test..so my mistake :)..Also, the uri was still constructed without specifying the controller .. I checked for both cases.what then is the controller for ?